# Is this number of active connections normal in a reverse ssh tunnel?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, tcp

I've some problems with TCP connections on my VPS. Sometimes the maximum number of connections allowed on the server is reached and ssh conections are refused. I've a few devices connected to the server by a reverse ssh tunnel, and I don't know if I manage these connections correctly.

In the example below I show the connections created only by 4 devices that I've connected by a reverse ssh tunnel.

```
[root@vps-pruebas ~]# netstat -naptu | grep fichar
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4404          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11988/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4401          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9896/sshd: ficharce
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4402          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11981/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4403          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9887/sshd: ficharce
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44780     ESTABLISHED 12386/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44778     ESTABLISHED 12347/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44758     ESTABLISHED 12179/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44736     ESTABLISHED 12011/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44754     ESTABLISHED 12149/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44768     ESTABLISHED 12253/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44776     ESTABLISHED 12345/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44788     ESTABLISHED 12436/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44742     ESTABLISHED 12044/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         203.0.68.60:12737       ESTABLISHED 9885/sshd: ficharce
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44760     ESTABLISHED 12183/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44770     ESTABLISHED 12282/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44740     ESTABLISHED 12020/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44732     ESTABLISHED 11979/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44786     ESTABLISHED 12427/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44762     ESTABLISHED 12185/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44752     ESTABLISHED 12147/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44790     ESTABLISHED 12468/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.28.223.129:54650     ESTABLISHED 11986/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44744     ESTABLISHED 12056/sshd: ficharc
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         203.0.68.60:47486       ESTABLISHED 9894/sshd: ficharce
tcp        0      0 38.59.113.62:22         81.32.245.105:44756     ESTABLISHED 12161/sshd: ficharc
tcp6       0      0 ::1:4404                :::*                    LISTEN      11988/sshd: ficharc
tcp6       0      0 ::1:4401                :::*                    LISTEN      9896/sshd: ficharce
tcp6       0      0 ::1:4402                :::*                    LISTEN      11981/sshd: ficharc
tcp6       0      0 ::1:4403                :::*                    LISTEN      9887/sshd: ficharce
```

Is it normal that for 4 devices connected by ssh so many active connections are generated?

EDIT to add the information required.
I've opened reverse tunnel on each device just for connected to them when I need to check anything. But, with Cron task, the device connect to VPS to check updates and put some files into server

Comment: It is totally unknown what these devices should do so it is unclear if it is normal for these kind of devices. But if you design your own communication then you could do with a single SSH connection per device and tunnel every traffic between the device and your server through this single connection.

Comment: To improve your question and in addition to Steffen i would generally recommend to outline your use case in more detail. The `netstat` is nice though, but the community needs to know, what you want to accomplish.

Comment: "Normal" depends on what services you provide and how these are used, and by how many.

Comment: I edited my question for add what do each device exactly. I'm going to read more about how I can use reverse tunnel for all connections between device and server